# Returning a list in python that is composed of .split() elements

Tags: python, list

In the code below, `getreport` is a text item that is formatted by `/t` and `/n`.
I am trying to output a list of phone numbers, but the returning list comes back like this: `['5','5','5','7','8','7', ...]` etc., instead of something like ['5557877777']. What is wrong here?

```
def parsereport(getreport):
listoutput = []
lines = re.findall(r'.+?\n' , getreport) #everything is in perfect lines
for m in lines:
    line = m
    linesplit = line.split('\t')  # Now I have a list of elements for each line
    phone = linesplit[0]  # first element is always the phone number ex '5557777878'
    if is_number(linesplit[10]) == True:
            num = int(linesplit[10])
            if num > 0:
                listoutput.extend(phone)
```

I tried putting print(phone) to test and it looks great and returns lines of '5557877777' etc but the returning list = ['5','5',etc] and the numbers are taken apart.

```
return listoutput
```

Comment: Why is there ``linesplit[10]``? Shouldn't it be ``linesplit[0]``? Or even ``phone``, for that matter?

Comment: Dimitri hit the nail right on the head. I was only taking the phone numbers(1st element) of the lines if the 11th element was a number and over 0.

Answer (score 6):

You will use `listoutput.append()` function instead of `listoutput.extend()`

```
>>> p='12345'
>>> l=[]
>>> l.extend(p)
>>> l
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> ll = []
>>> ll.append(p)
>>> ll
['12345']
```

[extend function:](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)
Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> Numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> NumbersJoined = []
>>> NumbersJoined.append(''.join(Numbers))
>>> print NumbersJoined
['12345']
```